Connection leak after upgrading to abp 9.2.2
Today I upgraded my asp.net boilerplate project nuget packages from 8.3.1 to 9.2.2 and started observing below exceptions afterwards.
24-04-30T19:07:26.461128248Z fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461154248Z       Connection id "0HN396GI5TOOM", Request id "0HN396GI5TOOM:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461159348Z       System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461162748Z        ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): The connection pool has been exhausted, either raise 'Max Pool Size' (currently 50) or 'Timeout' (currently 15 seconds) in your connection string.
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461167548Z        ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461170848Z          at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.<Get>g__RentAsync|34_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461174248Z          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|42_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461177548Z          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461180548Z          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461183548Z          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461192648Z          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461195748Z          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461199148Z          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<BeginTransaction>b__0(DatabaseFacade database)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461202548Z          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext _, TState s)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461205948Z          at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461209348Z          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461212548Z          at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461216348Z          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461219648Z          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.BeginTransaction(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461222749Z          at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.DbContextEfCoreTransactionStrategy.CreateDbContext[TDbContext](String connectionString, IDbContextResolver dbContextResolver)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461226149Z          at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.GetOrCreateDbContext[TDbContext](Nullable`1 multiTenancySide, String name)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461229349Z          at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.UnitOfWorkExtensions.GetDbContext[TDbContext](IActiveUnitOfWork unitOfWork, Nullable`1 multiTenancySide, String name)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461232549Z          at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.UnitOfWorkDbContextProvider`1.GetDbContext(Nullable`1 multiTenancySide)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461235749Z          at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.GetContext()
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461238849Z          at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.<GetQueryableAsync>b__8_0(Type key)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461242049Z          at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.GetQueryableAsync()
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461245149Z          at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.GetAllAsync()
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461248149Z          at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.FirstOrDefaultAsync(TPrimaryKey id)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461251349Z          at Abp.Authorization.Users.AbpUserStore`2.<>c__DisplayClass54_0.<<FindByIdAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461254849Z       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461257949Z          at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkManagerExtensions.WithUnitOfWorkAsync[TResult](IUnitOfWorkManager manager, Func`1 action, UnitOfWorkOptions options)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461263949Z          at Abp.Authorization.Users.AbpUserStore`2.FindByIdAsync(String userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461267049Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.ValidateSecurityStampAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461270149Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1.ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461273549Z          at Abp.Authorization.AbpSecurityStampValidator`3.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<ValidateAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461276849Z       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461280049Z          at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkManagerExtensions.WithUnitOfWorkAsync(IUnitOfWorkManager manager, Func`1 action, UnitOfWorkOptions options)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461283249Z          at Abp.Authorization.AbpSecurityStampValidator`3.ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461286449Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461289549Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461292549Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461295749Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461298949Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461302249Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461305549Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461308849Z          at Abp.AspNetCore.Security.AbpSecurityHeadersMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461312449Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
2024-04-30T19:07:26.461315649Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

On the database, I can see connections in state "idle in transaction" and the query is
SELECT a."Id", a."CreationTime", a."CreatorUserId", a."IsAbandoned", a."JobArgs", a."JobType", a."LastTryTime", a."NextTryTime", a."Priority", a."TryCount" FROM "AbpBackgroundJobs" AS a WHERE NOT (a."IsAbandoned") AND a."NextTryTime" <= $1 ORDER BY a."Priority" DESC, a."TryCount", a."NextTryTime" LIMIT $2

The problem is consistently occurring each time after application restart even when there is no request submitted to the application.
Any ideas on how to debug this issue futher?

The issue can be caused by BackgroundJobStore from Abp.BackgroundJobs.
They are calling async Task in a single WithUnitOfWork.
public virtual async Task<List<BackgroundJobInfo>> GetWaitingJobsAsync(int maxResultCount)
{
        return await _unitOfWorkManager.WithUnitOfWork(async() =>
        {
            var waitingJobsQuery = (await _backgroundJobRepository.GetAllAsync())
                ...
        });
}

To fix the issue, implement your custom BackgroundJobStore inheriting the Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobStore overriding GetWaitingJobsAsync with
public override async Task<List<BackgroundJobInfo>> GetWaitingJobsAsync(int maxResultCount)
{
    return await _unitOfWorkManager.WithUnitOfWorkAsync(async () =>
    {
        var waitingJobsQuery = (await _backgroundJobRepository.GetAllAsync())
        ...
    });
}

and then replace the Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobStore with your custom one in DI.
